# a few questions when iterator the arraylike object in javascript

Tags: javascript, iterator

In my application,I need to do some iteration with the array-like object.

So I write a custom util method:

```
Util.forEach=function(iterator,callback,context){
  if(iterator.length){
    for(var i=0;i<iterator.length;i++){
      var val=iterator[i];
      callback && callback.call(context||null,val,i);
    }
  }
}
```

Then I meet some problems:

Suppose I have an array: var ary=[1,2,3,4,5];

**1. how to break the loop?**

For example, if I want to find if value '2' is included in the array,I may try this:

```
Util.forEach(ary,function(value,index){
  if(value==2){
    //find mached value,now I should break and return this value.

    //but I can not use 'break' in this context.
  }
});
```

**2. remove value of the array when iterator**

If I want to remove value '2' of the array,I may try this:

```
Util.forEach(ary,function(value,index){
  if(value==2){
    //delete it.
    ary.splice(i,1);
    // I wonder if this is the safe way?
  }
});
```

Since in java we can not do this when iterate an array,it will cause the concurrency exception.

Though I run the above code without any error,but I am not sure if it is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue can be solved by checking the return value from the callback and stopping the iteration if it returns false.  Then you can stop the iteration by returning `false` from the callback.  Returning anything other than `false` (including returning nothing) will continue the iteration. jQuery uses this return value technique to cancel the iteration in their `.each()` iterator.  Adding that into your code, it would look like this:

```
Util.forEach=function(iterator,callback,context){
    if (iterator.length && callback) {
        for(var i = 0; i < iterator.length; i++){
            var val=iterator[i];
            if (callback.call(context||window,val,i) === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for forEach, you can see a sample implementation.

On the second issue, this type of implementaation does not permit insertion or deletion of elements at or before the iteration point because that will cause some elements to get skipped in the iteration or some objects to get iterated multiple times.  The obvious way around that would involve making a copy of the object before iterating which is not efficient when not needed.

Comment: thanks For your reply. for the second issue,as you say it is not efficient to make the copy,so any otherchoice?

Comment: @hguser - you can't have your cake and eat it too.  You either make a copy of the array so that changes to the original don't affect the iteration of every element.  Or, you live by a bunch of rules on what types of modifications are OK and what types are not.  Pick one or the other.  For example, it's OK to change any element.  It's even OK to add or remove any element after the current element.  It is just not OK to add/remove an element before or including the current element.

Comment: @hguser - If you want to add/remove before the current element, then write a `for` loop instead of using `.each(fn)` and you can manually control what happens to the iteration index when you modify the array according to what you want to happen for that specific situation.

Comment: So,is it mean that I can my code? Since I 'remove the current element.

Comment: @hguser - with `jQuery.each()`, removing the current element will cause the next element to be skipped.  You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JMtRp/.  That's because removing an element causes the next element to fall down into this element's place and the `.each()` loop doesn't know you did that so it is pointing at the next element, thus it never gets that element.  It also will attempt to be beyond the new length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can break out from a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)-like method by using `try`-`catch` and `throw`.

```
var value = 'Not Found';
try {
    Util.forEach(ary, function(value, index) {
       if(value == 2) {
           throw value; //<-- Throw the found result: Terminates current forEach
       }
    });
} catch (found) {       // Catch the thrown result
    value = found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to break the loop?

You're not supposed to break from `forEach`. That's why it's called "for each", and not "for some". "Breakable" JS iterators are `every()` (stops when the callback returns false) and `some()` (stops when the callback returns true).

Looking at your code once again it makes me think you actually want an `indexOf` kind of method, and not an iterator.

> remove value of the array when iterator

Iterators shouldn't make any changes of the underlying array. You have to implement `filter()` and use it to generate a new array.

See [js iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) for more details.

Comment: If you look carefully, you would see that the OP is not using `Array.prototype.forEach`, but a custom `Util.forEach` method.